# probability algorithm to find the next combination

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, probability

The best example that suits my problem is **Lottery** but its slightly different from lottery but idea is similar. My program is fetching data from database that stores previously generated numbers. The numbers are in following format:

```
...
5, 10, 11
...
```

3 **random** numbers. Now table holds up to **10,000** previously generated numbers the table format is following:

```
 UniqueID (autoincrement), Number1, Number2, Number3, DateOfGeneration
```

What kind of algorithm would i need or maybe suggest a book that will help me out come up with the algorithm. Im not asking you to write code for me im just asking for a tutorial or book or site so that i can read and figure it out myself.

I need to calculate the possible next combination that is most likely to come. Meaning lets say out of **10,000** previous generated combinations the combination **3, 5, 19** came up **350** times the probability of this combination to come up next time would be:

```
350/10000 = 0.035 or 3.5%
```

I would store this 0.035 in an array that has the following structure:

```
$arrayOfCombinations[combinationisthekey] = probability
```

example:

```
$arrayOfCombinations['3,5,19'] = 0.035
```

and then run some kind of algorithm that will pick randomly from this array the combination that is most likely to come so combination **3,5,19** would have **0.035** chance of getting picked.

I know how to get to the step of array holding all combinations and their probabilities. I need algorithm that will select randomly from array with their chance.

Do i need to consider Date that number was generated to make it more accurate? Does it have to increase/decrease the probability? These kind of factors that i need but dont know where to look for.

Any suggestions or links/tutorials are appreciated and thank you very much.

Again i'm not asking you to spend your time and write code for me. I will write it myself just need some kind of tutorial.

**EDIT: (read this for main point)**

The main thing that im looking for is: what kind of factors do i need to keep in mind that can increase/decrease the probability of a combination. Such as date of number being generated, whether the 3 numbers are even or odd etc... And when i get all these factors which algorithm would be best (if any) to plug in these data and get accurate result

Comment: If I'm understanding you, the phrase to search for is "weighted random selection" or "weighted random choice".  Depending on what language you're using, you'll probably find an implementation in the first few hits if you add the language name.  I'm not entirely certain I'm following you, though, because "pick randomly from this array the combination that is most likely to come" isn't the same thing as returning "3,5,19" 3.5% of the time.

Comment: Do I have this right: For each unique combination of Number1/Number2/Number3 you want the count of rows, divided by the total number of rows and expressed as a percentage.

Comment: @DSM I do know weighted random choice but im looking for a specific algorithm, i will implement it myself i dont use others code. Was wondering if its possible to add Date of generation as one of the factors that can increase/decrease probability

Comment: @PieterGeerkens yes but that part i know how to do it myself, i need something that will increase/decrease the probability of combination coming up based on date or based on number being odd/even etc... In short i need to know how to take multiple factors and plug it in to some calculator that will calculate the probability of it coming up

Comment: So you arelooking for assistance in building an algorithm for requirments that you have not completed specification of yet. I'll pass this time round; call back when you have decided what you want.

Comment: im looking for what kind of factors do i need to keep in mind to make it as accurate as possible

Comment: As you have described this so far it seems that you are trying to determine how your random number generator works? If correctly, over a large enough sample you will have an equal probability of selecting any number, again assuming a large enough sample and equal probability of selecting any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches come to mind.

First cut: instead of storing the probability in the array with the numbers as the index, you might try storing the numbers in the array with the index being a simple number (i.e. indexes are 1, 2, 3, etc).  You put one entry in the array for each entry in the table, then randomly select a number from 1..number of elements in the array.  Use this random number to extract the combination from the array.  In this manner you'll pull combinations from the array with the expected frequency.

Another option is to continue to use the combination as the key, but instead of storing the probability in the array you store the actual number of occurrences of each combinations (e.g. store 350 instead of .035).  Randomly choose a number from 1 to the total number of occurences and iterate through the array, subtracting off the occurrence count stored in the array from your random value until the random value becomes zero or negative, in which case the index of the element you just looked at is the combination you found.

If I had to do this I'd prefer #1 - it's simple and easy to implement.  #2 saves a bit of memory and 30 years ago would have been my choice, but today with gigabytes of real memory at our disposal I see no great reason to try and minimize the use of a non-critical resource.

YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compute probabilities for [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram); this is similar to what Google uses in natural language processing, and you are using numbers instead of words. There are many existing models for how to approach this problem.

One thing that you can do particularly efficiently is to estimate a Markov chain model on the numbers, which will efficiently store and give you the probabilities of all n-grams. This does make an assumption that only depends on the number that you've currently observed, though.